# Are Dapps really viable?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, dapps, bitcoin

i'm newbie in this topic and  i have so many doubts about dapps:

- Can Dapps run on the browser? I've just seen dapps wich should be installed, and i think this is a big obstacle to reach normal users, even to solve real life problems and revenue.

-Is there someone solving a real life problem with a Dapp and getting revenue for that? ie: social network, ecommerce platform, etc...

- Can you provide me a url of a tutorial to develop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, look at Metamask and Truffle!

A good example of Dapp is https://etheroll.com/  which runs in browser and connects to your ethereum account via metamask.   Truffle has good tutorials on how to develop them.  http://truffleframework.com/